# HttpSolrServer instance management

Tags: java, solr, thread-safety, solrj

Is it safe to share single HttpSolrServer across multiple threads in a web application? Is it recommended?

Is constructing a new instance each time expensive? At my machine it takes about 10ms.

Answer (score 3):

A few observations after looking at the source of `HttpSolrServer`(at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/3.6.0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.java))

1. There is no request specific data maintained as a class variable. So as long as all the configuration parameters (like base URL, Connection Timeout etc) are not modified by any thread, an instance of `HttpSolrServer` can be safely used in a multithread environment.
2. `HttpSolrServer` internally uses a class `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` which manages the thread-safety on internal http-client connection (*It uses Apache HTTP Client 4.x to connect to solr*). This ensures that there are no thread safety issues in communicating with the Solr server.

Comment: Do you use it this way? In what environment?

Comment: We use that but in a single threaded environment. As I mentioned, it can be safely used in a multithread environment.

Comment: You just think it can be safely used in a multithreaded environment after a simple analysis, that I did too. I wanted a statement: we use it so and it works reliably in production. I also use it this way so far and have no problem, but not in production.

Comment: Well my analysis is based on certain concrete facts. If I had scenario to use that in production, I will go ahead and do it after elaborate testing.

Answer (score 0):

please see below link may be this will help:
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Memory-problems-with-HttpSolrServer-td4060985.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.